# Grails code coverage not working

Tags: grails, cobertura

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and create JUnit Test for controller but code coverage not cover my test case of controller below are my test case detail.

```
//BuildConfig.groovy
plugins {
    test ":code-coverage:2.0.3-3"
}

//MyControllerTests.groovy
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(MyController)
@TestFor([Domain1,Domain2])
class MyControllerTests {
    void setUp() {
        controller.myService = new MyService()
    }

    void testAction1(){
        controller.action1()
    }
}


//mycontroller.groovy
class MyController {
   def myService
   def action1{
      def msg = myService.myFirstAction()
   }
}

//myservice.groovy
class MyService{
   def myFirstAction(){
     //logic which returns string
     return 'my logic result'
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you see no details at all I'm the coverage report? Can you share the console output?

Comment: When I change the code coverage version from test ":code-coverage:2.0.3-3" to test ":code-coverage:1.2.6" then it's work fine for me.

Comment: Can you provide the console text from running the coverage?